# Unix Make file error

Tags: unix

I am having difficulty compiling my makefile and I was wondering if I could receive any input on what I'm doing wrong. For some reason it's telling me I can't compile in shell and to use `linprog` instead?

```
CC = g++
DIR = /home/majors/dlowe/makefileHW
CFLAGS = -g -I. -c
LFLAGS = -g

make: main.o size.o history.o extra.o
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o make main.o size.o history.o extra.o
main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
size.o: size.cpp size.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) size.cpp
history.o: history.cpp history.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) history.cpp
extra.o: extra.cpp extra.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) extra.cpp
clean:
        rm -rf *.o
```

the errors are here:

```
enter code here
dlowe@shell.cs.fsu.edu:~/makefileHW> make -f Assignment7
g++ -g -I. -c main.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c size.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c history.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c extra.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -o make main.o size.o history.o extra.o
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
'
```

Comment: Please also include the full text of the error message you are seeing.

Comment: dlowe@shell.cs.fsu.edu:~/makefileHW> make -f Assignment7
g++ -g -I. -c main.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c size.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c history.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -I. -c extra.cpp
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.
g++ -g -o make main.o size.o history.o extra.o
No programming on shell. Please use linprog instead.

Comment: i apologize about the format i couldnt change it

Comment: Are you able to edit your question and paste it in there?

Comment: im using pico editor for the makefile by the way but i dont know why it wont compile

Comment: Type `g++ --version` on your shell prompt and see what happens.